# Accessing my Amazon AWS Tor Bridge

Tags: tor-cloud, ssh

I just set up a Tor Bridge on a Amazon AWS Server (very good explanation how to do that on https://cloud.torproject.org/).

Now its up and running and I try to access it. I copied the private key (tor-cloud-servers.pem) into my home directory and then tried:

```
ssh -i tor-cloud-server.pem root@ec2-54-221-135-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

But it says "Identity file tor-cloud-server.pem not accessible. No such file or directory".

How can I solve this?

Comment: not sure if this got solved but you must connect as ubuntu@ec2-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx... not as root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `ssh` can't find your key file.  Is the file name `tor-cloud-server.pem` or `tor-cloud-servers.pem`?

And are you running this command from your home directory?  If not, try an absolute path:

`ssh -i ~/tor-cloud-server.pem root@ec2-54-221-135-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Comment: to add something to the previous answer, there is also another possibility for a different user that this .pem file downloaded has a difference extension other than the required .pem. such behaviour has beeen noted in some browsers and Amason advices that file *only* requires renaming.